# Should we store data in database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i'm asp.net beginner and currently working in "upload download file" project with asp.net and vb.net as code behind language (like skydrive's web). 

 
what i'm want ask is about upload file in server, must we store path file, size, accessed or created date into database? as we know we can use directory listing in system.io.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use file system, too much I/O requests can be a downside for your application.Database is the best choice to store pah, size , accessed etc information while the file should actually reside on filesystem.

Comment: If you're using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 you might want to look into the new FileTable feature http://www.midnightdba.com/Jen/2013/03/filetable-sql-server-2012s-little-gasp-maker/

Comment: @StephenKennedy thanks for pointing that out... nice to know mssql2012 have this cool feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definetly want to store the path of the file. You want a way to find the file ;) Maybe later you will have multiple servers, replication or other fancy things.

For the rest, it depends a bit on the type of website. If it's going to get high traffic then store it in the database, this will limit the number of IO call (very slow). Also, it'll be a lot easier to handle sorting and queries. (sort by date, pull only the read onyl files, ...).

Database will also help if you want to show history or statistique.

Answer (score 0):

You can save file in some directory and can save path of that file in database. You can also store size and created date of that file in DB. But storing a file in DB is a bit difficult. Rather than save file in Directory and save path of that file in DB

Answer (score 0):

you could store the file information in a database to built some extra features like "avoid storing duplicate files", because you are having a faster search in the database! if you search the filesystem always a recursive function call get started